# Camera flies off when trying to set camera bounds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

The player controls the camera movement to look around the level and I am trying to set boundaries so the camera cannot go too far. However, when I have the boundary code added, the camera flies off whenever I press a button to move.

```
 if (Input.GetKey("d"))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(camSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));

            transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minX, maxX), 0);


        }
        if (Input.GetKey("a"))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(-camSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));

            transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minX, maxX), 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, camSpeed * Time.deltaTime));

            transform.position = new Vector2(0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minY, maxY));
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("s"))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, -camSpeed * Time.deltaTime));

            transform.position = new Vector2(0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minY, maxY));
        }
```

I have set values min and max values to higher than needed levels and the camera still flies off, no matter what the values are set to.

Comment: What are your values of `minY`, `maxY`, `minX`, and `maxX`?

Comment: @Ruzihm No matter what the values are it flies off. Currently to test it they are -1000 and 1000.

Comment: First of all, you probably shouldn't set `transform.position = new Vector2(0, Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minY, maxY));` in every `if`, just do it once at the end. The way you have it now, you will set X position to 0 every time you move Y position and vice versa.

Comment: @FredrikSchön I have just moved it out and now it just starts in the middle of nowhere.  I have also changed it to `transform.position = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minX, maxX), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minY, maxY));`

Comment: is it 2d or 3d?

Comment: Because you're ignoring the Z value, which will set it to 0. Vector2(x, y) == Vector3(x, y, 0)

Comment: @TomMcMillan Get the camera to "fly off" and let us know what position it is at at that time.

Comment: @FredrikSchön it is 2D

Comment: Is the camera a child to any other object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain my comment; instead of setting x to 0 every time you move with W or S you should move the clamping to the end, and clamp both x and y (and probably keep Z value?):

```
if (Input.GetKey("d"))
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector2(camSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
}
if (Input.GetKey("a"))
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector2(-camSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));
}
if (Input.GetKey("w"))
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, camSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}
if (Input.GetKey("s"))
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector2(0, -camSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
}

transform.position = new Vector3(
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, minX, maxX), 
    Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, minY, maxY), 
    transform.position.z
);
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you!